# What is the best way of embedding a java applet into my webpage?

Tags: java, html, standards-compliance, applet

I've been looking into putting a little Java application in my web page, but the more research I do, the more confused I become about how I should do it. Sun suggests [many ways](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#applet) of doing it, but it looks suspiciously like it's from the Netscape era.

So, should I use `<applet>`, as suggested by eclipse, `<embed>`, or `<object>`?

And how should I use the correct tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 6 Update 10 they've released a [Java Deployment Kit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit):

> The Java Deployment Toolkit makes
>   deploying Java applets or Java Web
>   Start programs a snap. The Deployment
>   Toolkit JavaScript file provides:
>
> ```
> * Accurate detection of installed JREs
> * Seamless JRE installation
> * Complete applet launching (JRE detection and, if necessary, upgrading) 
>   in a single line of code
> * Complete Web Start program launching in a single line of code
> ```
>
> The following HTML code is all it
>   takes to ensure that Java 1.6 is
>   installed and then a Java applet is
>   launched:

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<script>
  deployJava.runApplet({codebase:"http://www.example.com/applets/",
     archive:"ExampleApplet.jar", code:"Main.class",
     width:"320", Height:"400"}, null, "1.6");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to strictly follow standards then a quick look [here at the W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.4) says that applet is depreciated and you should use object instead.

Comment: Exactly how are you supposed to use the `<object>` tag for including java applets?

Comment: @Eric: I get depreciated and deprecated confused, sorry. And yes, you can use object: http://depth-first.com/articles/2008/02/20/demystifying-java-applets-part-1-cross-browser-standards-compliant-pure-html-deployment-using-the-object-tag . Scroll down to "A Better Way: Deployment with the <object> Tag". However the solution by Dougnukem is much better